# Why can't I install Perl's File::Find::Rule?

Tags: perl, cpan

```
perl -MCPAN -e'install File::Find::Rule'
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
Going to read /root/.cpan/Metadata
  Database was generated on Mon, 13 Sep 2010 08:41:13 GMT
Running install for module File::Find::Rule
Running make for R/RC/RCLAMP/File-Find-Rule-0.32.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::MD5 loaded ok
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RC/RCLAMP/File-Find-Rule-0.32.tar.gz ok
File-Find-Rule-0.32/
File-Find-Rule-0.32/Changes
File-Find-Rule-0.32/findrule
File-Find-Rule-0.32/lib/
File-Find-Rule-0.32/lib/File/
File-Find-Rule-0.32/lib/File/Find/
File-Find-Rule-0.32/lib/File/Find/Rule/
File-Find-Rule-0.32/lib/File/Find/Rule/Extending.pod
File-Find-Rule-0.32/lib/File/Find/Rule/Procedural.pod
File-Find-Rule-0.32/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm
File-Find-Rule-0.32/Makefile.PL
File-Find-Rule-0.32/MANIFEST
File-Find-Rule-0.32/META.yml
File-Find-Rule-0.32/README
File-Find-Rule-0.32/t/
File-Find-Rule-0.32/t/File-Find-Rule.t
File-Find-Rule-0.32/t/findrule.t
File-Find-Rule-0.32/testdir/
File-Find-Rule-0.32/testdir/File-Find-Rule.t
File-Find-Rule-0.32/testdir/findrule.t
File-Find-Rule-0.32/testdir/foobar
File-Find-Rule-0.32/testdir/lib/
File-Find-Rule-0.32/testdir/lib/File/
File-Find-Rule-0.32/testdir/lib/File/Find/
File-Find-Rule-0.32/testdir/lib/File/Find/Rule/
File-Find-Rule-0.32/testdir/lib/File/Find/Rule/Test/
File-Find-Rule-0.32/testdir/lib/File/Find/Rule/Test/ATeam.pm
Removing previously used /root/.cpan/build/File-Find-Rule-0.32

  CPAN.pm: Going to build R/RC/RCLAMP/File-Find-Rule-0.32.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Number::Compare 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Text::Glob 0.07 not found.
Writing Makefile for File::Find::Rule
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during [R/RC/RCLAMP/File-Find-Rule-0.32.tar.gz] -----
    Number::Compare
    Text::Glob
Shall I follow them and prepend them to the queue
of modules we are processing right now? [yes] yes
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module Number::Compare
Running make for R/RC/RCLAMP/Number-Compare-0.01.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RC/RCLAMP/Number-Compare-0.01.tar.gz ok
Number-Compare-0.01/
Number-Compare-0.01/MANIFEST
Number-Compare-0.01/t/
Number-Compare-0.01/t/Number-Compare.t
Number-Compare-0.01/MANIFEST.SKIP
Number-Compare-0.01/Compare.pm
Number-Compare-0.01/Changes
Number-Compare-0.01/Makefile.PL
Removing previously used /root/.cpan/build/Number-Compare-0.01

  CPAN.pm: Going to build R/RC/RCLAMP/Number-Compare-0.01.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Number::Compare
     -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running install for module Text::Glob
Running make for R/RC/RCLAMP/Text-Glob-0.08.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RC/RCLAMP/Text-Glob-0.08.tar.gz ok
Text-Glob-0.08/
Text-Glob-0.08/META.yml
Text-Glob-0.08/Changes
Text-Glob-0.08/MANIFEST
Text-Glob-0.08/t/
Text-Glob-0.08/t/Text-Glob.t
Text-Glob-0.08/lib/
Text-Glob-0.08/lib/Text/
Text-Glob-0.08/lib/Text/Glob.pm
Text-Glob-0.08/README
Text-Glob-0.08/Makefile.PL
Text-Glob-0.08/Build.PL
Removing previously used /root/.cpan/build/Text-Glob-0.08

  CPAN.pm: Going to build R/RC/RCLAMP/Text-Glob-0.08.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Text::Glob
     -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running make for R/RC/RCLAMP/File-Find-Rule-0.32.tar.gz
  Is already unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/File-Find-Rule-0.32

  CPAN.pm: Going to build R/RC/RCLAMP/File-Find-Rule-0.32.tar.gz

     -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

How can i make this?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is in the Number::Compare installation; run its unit tests to see where it is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only install:

```
apt-get install libfile-find-rule-perl
```

And it works!!

Comment: If you are installing modules into the system's copy of Perl you should only use the systems package management tool.  Mixing self-built and system built modules is a recipe for disaster.  If you must install modules directly from CPAN, always use something like [`local::lib`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/local-lib/lib/local/lib.pm) to protect yourself.

Comment: Installing a module from a package likely totally bypasses running its unit tests and those of its dependencies, which would be masking any potential issue you would have with actually using the module. (this is another reason why I despise using a package manager for CPAN libraries.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [`Number::Compare`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Number-Compare/Compare.pm) and [`Text::Glob`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Glob-0.08/lib/Text/Glob.pm) failed to install.  Download `Number::Compare` and build it manually to see what the problem is.  Do the same for `Text::Glob` .

Comment: They are already downloaded; at the CPAN shell, do `look Number Compare` and then manually try `perl Makefile.PL` (`perl Build.PL` for Text::Glob)